# UIView connected to 2 IBOutlets

Tags: iphone, ios, iboutlet

I have a view controller and it has connected via xib. In that xib I have a seperate view and I connected this same view to 2 different IBoutlets and added this view to main view. But in the outlet the view which I added second is only visible. The first one is not able to see. Why?

Comment: Certainly because you can connect a view to one and only one outlet ?

Comment: No I can connect a view to two IBOutlets

Comment: You probably use them as if they are connected to different views. You do not need to have several outlet linked to the same view inside the same file. You can already do everything with only one outlet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is possible to connect two outlets to the same view object, it is rarely advisable to doing so. In your case this is only one UIView (subclassed) object. Both IBOutlet 'pointers' refer to the same (individual) object.

If you now setup both, first and then the second, layout them etc. then you will have the impression that only the second one is visible. That is what you are saying.

Lets assume you have layouted your left view first and your right view second then it appears to you that only the right view is visible.
If you now turn around the secuence of layouting statements (what ever that ist, position, size, frame, colour, ...) and layout the right view and then the left view, only the left view will appear. This is simply because you managed to link the same object to two IBOutlets. By layouting the second one you simply overwrite the layout data that you set in the first hand.

From what I read between the lines in your case I would suggest to create (probably duplicate) an additional UIView (or whatever subclass) in IB and link them accordingly to one IBOutlet each.

Comment: Then, why there is an option of connecting two IBOutlets to a single view? Is there any use?

Comment: Difficult to say. Sometimes it is helpful having two references to the same object. In complex projects parts of your code may refer to a standard UIView and some other part may refer to a specific subclass of UIView. Having two reverences might avoid typecasts. From my point of view it is certainly not neccessary.  -  Sometimes this happens in IB when you copy view items around. In those cases it is simply an error that does not do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect two IBOutlet to a single Object, but I don't think it will help you,

It's like you are calling Same person with two names X and Y, and then asking, Hey! You are Y, where is X I can't see him :).

What I can suggest is If you want two subviews to be visible at a same time them add two UIViews each one is connected to a single IBOutlet, else use only single UIView connected to a single IBOutlet and try to make a toggle logic
for ex:

```
if(isConditionForViewOne){
//Change UI accordingly
  view.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor orangeColor];
}
else if(isConditionForViewTwo){
//Change UI accordingly
view.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```